# Is it possible to read a file in tcl given that the tcl code is still writing?

Tags: tcl

I have the following code -

```
set fh [open /home/user/file1 a+]

for { set i 0 } {i < 3600 } { incr i } {

puts $fh "This is the $i line"

}

# If I open the file before closing the file handler, the file is empty. How do I
# access it here?

close $fh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `a+` mode](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm#M10) opens for both reading and writing (creating the file if necessary), but the initial position in the file is at the end so that you can append data to it (which is what `a` stands for). To read anything useful, you must [`seek`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/seek.htm) to somewhere other than the end first.

```
seek $fh 0
set firstLine [gets $fh]
```

Note that this is in contrast to the `r+` mode, which sets the initial position to the *start* of the file, and the `w+` mode, which truncates the file on opening. (For completeness, there's also `r` which is read-only, `w` which is write-only, and `a` which is append-only and sets a special OS flag to enforce that strictly on platforms that support such semantics.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can both read and write from a file, but you must open it for read/write access. Opening the file with the a+ flag does not allow reading from the file:

> a+...Open the file for writing. The file does not exist, create it.
>   Set the current location to the end of the file.

What you want to do is open the file in r+ mode if it exists, or if it does not exist, in w+ mode. That will allow you to use read operations on the file.

See more information on file access modes in TCL [here.](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl24.html)

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it worked fine.

set fh [open /tmp/test.csv a+]
fconfigure $fh -buffering line

This spits out line by line into the file. So at any given point of time while my script is being executed, I can open the CSV file and see the data. Other options include the following -

```
tcl> set fh [open test a+]
file13
tcl> fconfigure $fh -buffering none
tcl> puts $fh "line 1"
tcl> puts $fh "line 2"
tcl> puts $fh "line 3"

[vm@ testserver]$ more test
line 1
line 2
line 3

tcl> fconfigure $fh -buffering full
tcl> puts $fh "line 4"
tcl> puts $fh "line 5"
tcl> puts $fh "line 6"

[vm@ testserver]$ more test
line 1
line 2
line 3


tcl> fconfigure $fh -buffering line
tcl> puts $fh "line 7"
tcl> puts $fh "line 8"
tcl> puts $fh "line 9"

[vm@ testserver]$ more test
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
[vm@ test]$
```

Thank you Kenneth Aalberg and Donal Fellows.

Appreciate the superfast responses!

Comment: You may wish to check whichever answer you found most useful as "correct" (to indicate to other potential answerers that you have an answer) and upvote either or both of the answers that you found useful.